# How to merge results of two jQuery AJAX calls and use deferred/promise

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to merge the results of two jQuery AJAX calls. I've looked at other similar questions here, but none of them seem to help. For each ajax call (2 of them), I have a success that calls the function createStatusView and it passes it the results. The good part is that the results work for both of the AJAX calls. The bad news is that my $.when call returns undefined for both res1 and res2, which then send undefined for the results to my createStatusView. So, I really don't want to invoke the createStatusView for both of the AJAX calls, only the $.when. Any recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

```
function getSpecifiedList(listName, userId){

    var url = SP.PageContextInfo.get_webServerRelativeUrl() + "/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/" + listName;

    var url1 = url + "?$select=ParentOrg,ORG,URL,Site_Status&$inlinecount=allpages";       
    var call1 = $.ajax({
        url: url1,
        type: "GET",
        headers:{"accept":"application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: function(results){createStatusView(results, listName);},
        error:function(error){
            console.log("Error in getting List: " + listName);
            $(_options.container).html("Error retrieving your " + listName + ". " + 
            SP.PageContextInfo.get_webServerRelativeUrl());
        }
    });

    var url2 = url + "?$select=ParentOrg,ORG,URL,Site_Status&$inlinecount=allpages&$skiptoken=1000";
    var call2 = $.ajax({
        url: url2,
        type: "GET",
        headers:{"accept":"application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: function(results){createStatusView(results, listName);},
        error:function(error){
            console.log("Error in getting List: " + listName);
            $(_options.container).html("Error retrieving your " + listName + ". " + 
            SP.PageContextInfo.get_webServerRelativeUrl());
        }
    });
    //the res1 and res2 come back undefined
            //call1 and call2 are objects as shown in F12 debug
    $.when(call1,call2).done(function(res1,res2){
        var results = res1[0].d.results.concat(res2[0].d.results);
        createStatusView(results,listName);
    });
}
```

Comment: What is createStatusView supposed to return? Your $.ajax success handlers are not returning anything to the caller... do you want to feed your `$.when.done` callback with the data returned by the ajax calls?

Comment: createStatusView just processes the data or in this case, the results and displays them in a web page. It works but didn't want to include it because of the extra amount of code. If I comment out the $.when, both the ajax calls work properly, the only problem is that the processing that takes place in createStatusView happens two times instead of once and I end up getting two different chunks of data displayed on my page, whereas, I want to merge the results and process them all at once so that my layout and logic work correctly

Answer (score 2):

Try adding some object detection to your $.when callback function. It will keep the undefined values out of your list.

```
$.when(call1,call2).done(function(res1,res2){
    var results = res1[0].d.results.concat(res2[0].d.results);
    if (results) {
        createStatusView(results,listName);
    }
});
```

Another example:

```
$.when(call1,call2).done(function(res1,res2){
   if (!res1 && !res2) return;
   var results = res1[0].d.results.concat(res2[0].d.results);
   if (results) {
      createStatusView(results,listName);
   }
});
```

Which is the same as this:

```
$.when(call1,call2).done(function(res1,res2){
   if (res1 && res2) {
      var results = res1[0].d.results.concat(res2[0].d.results);
      if (results) {
         createStatusView(results,listName);
      }
   }
});
```

Comment: I also added some tests but they didn't help solve the problem.

Comment: I think I see what you're really asking about. You're looking for a way to merge 2 objects together, like this: `var mergedResults = $.extend({},model.ajax1Results,model.ajax2Results);
createStatusView(mergedResults, listName);` I've added an extended answer to this jsfiddle with 3 options for you to choose from, but they will all require additional code: https://jsfiddle.net/briankueck/tpgzbax4/ The core component is jQuery's $.extend() function. My jsfiddle illustrates how to track both Ajax callbacks & run the createStatusView function only 1x with the merged results.

Comment: From your jsfiddle, mine is mostly working. For my calls to mergeCallbacks, I had to add the key of "ajax1Results" and "ajax2Results". Now I'm at the mergeCallbacks function and it works until the $.extend. The $.extend isn't working, my mergeResults contains 25 objects (should be 1025) in the result = ajax2Results. ajax1Results is being ignored or overwritten. I also tried doing $.extend( ajax1Results,ajax2Results) but it still only gets the ajax2Results. I reordered ajax1Results and ajax2Results, I get the reverse which is 1000 objects in the object array. Thx

Comment: I created a jsfiddle based on your script: [https://jsfiddle.net/M_66/0taxbnw3](https://jsfiddle.net/M_66/0taxbnw3)

Comment: I added the structure of the jquery ajax result to my jsfiddle in case that helps.

Comment: Oops, I forgot to include that key from the calling functions. Sorry about that! This is a rare case here on SO where I can only guide you, but I can't test out the final code. Since I don't have access to your .svc files, I can't make the Ajax calls nor see the results from them. So I'm creating the code by just thinking off of the top of my head with how I'd start out programming it. You'll have to actually integrate it into your code & then start debugging it from there. Although, I just had another idea... Let me try bypassing the Ajax calls using some mock array data. Be back soon...

Comment: Ok try this new jsfiddle, which has a working merge example with mock data in it: https://jsfiddle.net/briankueck/zxuy295c/ (If the debugger is turned on, it will show how the object fills up with data. When it's turned off, console.log() shows the final state of the object having 2 objects in it. It's not showing them individually as the data is inserted into it... before the $.extend() runs.)

Comment: Ok, still didn't work. I decided to create an array (_ultimateObjectHolderArr) within the namespace. I push the results of each AJAX call into the array. That works fine. Now I'm running into the problem of timing and where to put my createStatusView call to create the view, at its current location in my [code](https://jsfiddle.net/M_66/0taxbnw3/), it calls it twice, but I only need to call it once after array built. I think I need to use jQuery deferred/promise, but not sure how. Updated jsfiddle: [https://jsfiddle.net/M_66/0taxbnw3/](https://jsfiddle.net/M_66/0taxbnw3/)

Comment: I think I should move this to another thread since the nature of the question has changed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried moving the ajax calls to separate functions then calling those from the when?

```
function getSpecifiedList(listName, userId){
    $.when(call1(listName),call2(listName)).then(function(res1,res2){
        var results = res1[0].d.results.concat(res2[0].d.results);
        createStatusView(results,listName);
    });
}

function call1(listName){   
    var url = SP.PageContextInfo.get_webServerRelativeUrl() + "/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/" + listName;
    var url1 = url + "?$select=ParentOrg,ORG,URL,Site_Status&$inlinecount=allpages";   

    return $.ajax({
        url: url1,
        type: "GET",
        headers:{
            "accept":"application/json;odata=verbose",
        }
    }); 
};

function call2(listName){
    var url = SP.PageContextInfo.get_webServerRelativeUrl() + "/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/" + listName;
    var url2 = url + "?$select=ParentOrg,ORG,URL,Site_Status&$inlinecount=allpages&$skiptoken=1000";
    return $.ajax({
        url: url2,
        type: "GET",
        headers:{
            "accept":"application/json;odata=verbose",
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Yep, had already tried that. Here are the results: Unable to get property 'results' of undefined or null reference